# Cookie is undefined after redirect in mobile Safari

Tags: php, cookies, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I have a little bit of code that set's a `$userid` cookie and then redirects as follows:

```
$userid = $_GET['userid'];
setcookie('userid',$userid,time() + (864000 * 7), '/');

header("Location: https://coinbase.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=$clientid&redirect_uri=$redirecturi");
```

This works fine. If I echo `$_COOKIE['userid']` after setting it, it displays the userid. So far so good.

The redirect is to a Coinbase OAuth page where the user has to login and allow my site access to their wallet. After the process Coinbase redirects the user to the `$redirecturi`, which is the same page as the set cookie code is on.

I am then using `$_COOKIE['userid']` to determine which user went through the authentication process and store the data I received from Coinbase. Also, I do check if `$_GET['code']` is set, so the two parts of code are separated (I'm not accidentally setting `$_GET['userid']` as the cookie again).

Example urls:

Script location: `http://example.com/dev/startcoinbase.php?userid=abcdef`

URL for the user: `http://example.com/dev/startcoinbase.php?userid=abcdef`

Redirect from Coinbase: `http://example.com/dev/startcoinbase.php?code=code`

The really weird thing is that my code works just fine when running from within a UIwebview in an iOS app, on Chrome and FF on desktop, but just not in the mobile Safari browser (even though in app webviews use the same engine?!).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the domain AND the protocol `http / https` the same? Cookies for `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` can be different.

Also be wary with subdomains, maybe `sub.example.com` cookies can be not visible at `example.com`.

You should check (I think you did, but if not, then do), if you have cookies enabled in Safari :)

Comment: One domain was with www. prefixed and the other not.. Stupid error, but thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: No problem! Try to always stick to one domain, with `www` or `non-www`. Don't mix it. It has big impact on google and seo stuff too :)